# How to turn this pseudo-code into a Python program?

Tags: python

How can I turn this pseudo-code into a Python program on a cash machine?

```
OUTPUT “Menu”
OUTPUT “1 – Cash withdrawal”
OUTPUT “2 – Balance”
OUTPUT “3 – PIN Services”
OUTPUT “4 – Pay bills”
OUTPUT “5 – Cancel”
OUTPUT “Please select an option 1-5:”
user_option ← USERINPUT

IF user_option = 1 THEN 
    proc_withdrawal()
ELSEIF user_option = 2 THEN 
    proc_balance()
ELSEIF user_option = 3 THEN 
    proc_pin()
ELSEIF user_option = 2 THEN 
    proc_bills()
ELSEIF user_option = 2 THEN 
    proc_cancel()
ELSE
    OUTPUT “Please only enter an option 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5”
ENDIF
```

Comment: Did you try anything by yourself?

Comment: You are close. The next step is to go over an elementary Python tutorial.

Comment: Do you want to implement those functions? If so, what are you stuck on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this note the differences between the psudeo code and the actual code and that since you want compare the users input to a number you need to convert the string input to a int:

```
import sys

def proc_withdrawal():
  print("Your proc_withdrawal code goes here")

def proc_balance():
  print("Your proc_balance code goes here")

def proc_pin():
  print("Your proc_pin code goes here")

def proc_bills():
  print("Your proc_bills code goes here")

def proc_cancel():
  print("Thank you for using Simon Raivid's Cash Machine, Have a nice day!")
  sys.exit(0)

while True:
  print("Simon Raivid's Cash Machine")
  print("===========================")
  print("\t1 – Cash withdrawal")
  print("\t2 – Balance")
  print("\t3 – PIN Services")
  print("\t4 – Pay bills")
  print("\t5 – Cancel")
  user_option = int(input("Please select an option 1-5: "))

  if user_option == 1:
    proc_withdrawal()
  elif user_option == 2: 
    proc_balance()
  elif user_option == 3: 
    proc_pin()
  elif user_option == 4: 
    proc_bills()
  elif user_option == 5: 
    proc_cancel()
  else:
    print("Please only enter an option 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5")
```

**Example Usage:**

```
Simon Raivid's Cash Machine
===========================
    1 – Cash withdrawal
    2 – Balance
    3 – PIN Services
    4 – Pay bills
    5 – Cancel
Please select an option 1-5:  4
Your proc_bills code goes here!
Simon Raivid's Cash Machine
===========================
    1 – Cash withdrawal
    2 – Balance
    3 – PIN Services
    4 – Pay bills
    5 – Cancel
Please select an option 1-5:  5
Thank you for using Simon Raivid's Cash Machine, Have a nice day!
```

Comment: thank you very much